# Is there a Cadence metric that can help spot overloads for each specific activity worker?

Tags: cadence-workflow, uber-cadence

My company would like to automatically scale the activity workers and each workflow workers independently according to the load of a tasklist.

Reading the docs I have found the following metrics for activity workers:

- cadence_activity_scheduled_to_start_latency_bucket
- cadence_activity_scheduled_to_start_latency_count
- cadence_activity_scheduled_to_start_latency_sum

However these seem to be global metrics for activity workers. Is there a Cadence metric that would allow me to spot overloads for each specific activity worker?

Example:
We have 4 different activity workers : A, B, C and D
We would like to scale independently A or B or C or D without impacting the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Understand scheduled_to_start_latency

`scheduled_to_start_latency` is a measurement of the time from scheduled to started by worker. From scheduled to started, a task is transferred from matching service to an activity worker.

These are the potential hotspots when this latency got high:

- The matching service is too hot to dispatch tasks -- in this case, need to confirm with CPU/memory of the matching nodes
- The tasklist is overloaded because it defaults to have one partition which mapped to only one matching node: https://cadenceworkflow.io/docs/operation-guide/maintain/#scale-up-a-tasklist-using-scalable-tasklist-feature  -- in this case, use task per second metrics to confirm the task rate of the tasklist
- The activity worker is overloaded.

### How to monitor activity worker being overloaded

- CPU/memory/Thread usage/Garbage collection of the activity worker is usually enough to make sure an worker is not overloaded
- You can also use `scheduled_to_start_latency`, but the high latency could mean different things like above. Use other metrics to rule out the causes.